# Pythons if, elif and else statements

Tags: python

jeffs59
11:08 PM
I keep getting a syntax  error on the elif command.  I would be grateful if someone could point out what it is I am doing wrong.

```
if x > y:
    return -1
elif:
    if x == y:
        return 0
else: 
    if x < y:
        return -1
```

(https://repl.it/HTNB/0)

I went to:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

From what I could understand the code should work.

Comment: Post relevant part of code not a link. Questions should be self contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elif` expects a condition afterwards, just like a normal `if`. It should look like:

```
def compare_function(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return -1
    elif x == y:
        return 0
    else:
        assert x < y
        return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd line of `elif` should be like the following:

```
if x > y:
  return -1

elif x == y:
  return 0

else:
  if x < y:
```

Comment: Much appreciated.  I may have never figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is short version

```
def compare_function(x,y):
    return -1 if x > y else 0 if x == y else 1
```